# Accessing Tivoli Performance Module

Tags: performance, threadpool, business-process-management, tivoli

I am trying to extract the PMI data using a Java Application, I already been able to access performance module, but unfortunately, i cannot access SubModule as in the below example.

I extracted the ThreadPool Module data using this code

```
StatDescriptor mysd = new StatDescriptor(new String[] { PmiConstants.THREADPOOL_MODULE });
            MBeanStatDescriptor mymsd = new MBeanStatDescriptor(nodeAgent, mysd);
            Object[] params = new Object[]{mymsd, new Boolean(false)};  
            String[] signature = new String[] { "com.ibm.websphere.pmi.stat.MBeanStatDescriptor", "java.lang.Boolean" };
            com.ibm.ws.pmi.stat.StatsImpl myStats = (StatsImpl) adminClient.invoke(perfOn, "getStatsObject", params, signature);
            //System.out.println("myStats Size = " + myStats.dataMembers().size()+ "\n" + myStats.toString());
```

but I cannot access Threadpool submodules and their counters as AriesThreadPool

any recommended suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem 
just I enabled the recursively searching
by replacing the parameter from false to true

Object[] params = new Object[]{mymsd, new Boolean(true)};